# Why does my script keep looping over the files? Python

Tags: python

Hi essentially my script below works but then once its looped and counted over all the files it then keeps doing it again and again. Is there something weird in my code?
I'm also using the dirs, files and, name variables in the code any help you could give would be great

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(input):
    for name in files:

        if "fvds" in root:
            count = 0
            for gz in glob.glob(path.join(root, "*.gz")):
                print "Processing", gz
                with gzip.open(gz) as gzfile:
                    count += len(gzfile.readlines())
                print "%i features read" % count
                text_file.write("%i features read" % count+"\n")
```

Comment: Which OS are you running on, are there any recursive directory links? have you tried printing out root, dirs, files? What is `input`

Comment: Running on windows 7, all of my other variables seem fine and are used elsewhere in the script, printing out root makes it look like my code is working its just that it keeps doing everything over an dover.

Comment: Is it possible that whatever is calling this code is calling it repeatedly? What happens if you take that code segment and run it in a Python interpreter?

Answer (score -1):

you are opening your gzipped files in the the folder that you are walking over , this is creating another file for it to loop over when the files don't exist. This will trigger another iteration of os.walk as the new file arrives.

Comment: Would the person who downvoted this answer provide a reason?

Comment: Because the gzip.open isn't generating files AFAIK.

Comment: Thats what i thought, surely that temporary GZ object can't be walked over?

Comment: if you dont specify the mode it will create the file , the file will be the path witth a gz on the end. I would expect a lot of "0 features read" in the output